# Is there a word for "male libido"?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a single word for "male libido", "sexual stamina" and the like that's typically used with the word "traditional Asian medicine". There's a good-sounding word that was often used, but I completely forgot what it was.

Here's an example:

> Rhino horn powder is used by traditional Asian medicine enthusiasts for ___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly "rhino horn powder is used as an aphrodisiac"? That's not directly a word for libido, but it's the word usually used to describe this.

Answer (score 1):

"Aphrodisiac" is the general term for any substance that enhances libido or sexual desire.  It is not, however, specifically male or female.

There are many colloquial phrases for this, of course, e.g. "put more ram in your rod" (a play off the word "ramrod"), but these are generally crude and not used in formal literature.